# Swift - Update a UIButtton when CABasicAnimation is complete

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, cashapelayer, cabasicanimation

I am trying to say wherever a button is selected or not when the CAbasicanimation is completed. The animation starts on certain button when pressed.

When the button is clicked I store the button tag value into an integer "currentSelectedMarker". This does work and provide the wanted result but if another button is pressed before the animation isn't finish, it will update that clicked button instead of the original button which has the animation.

I know it's because the value of "currentSelectedMarker" is updated when any button is pressed but what would be a way to update the correct button when the animation is finished. Below is the code i am using for the animation.

```
func AutoUpRadial(button: UIButton, height: Int, value: Int){

    let trackLayer = CAShapeLayer()

    let radius = height / 3
    let circularPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: button.center, radius: CGFloat(radius), startAngle: 0, endAngle: 2 * CGFloat.pi, clockwise: true)
    trackLayer.path = circularPath.cgPath

    trackLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    trackLayer.opacity = 0.3
    trackLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    trackLayer.lineWidth = 5
    trackLayer.strokeEnd = 0

    mainScrollView.layer.addSublayer(trackLayer)

    autoUpFillRadial(value: value, tmpBtn: button, shape: trackLayer)
}

@objc private func autoUpFillRadial(value: Int, tmpBtn: UIButton, shape: CAShapeLayer){

    let basicAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")
    basicAnimation.toValue = 1
    basicAnimation.duration = CFTimeInterval(value)
    basicAnimation.fillMode = .forwards
    basicAnimation.isRemovedOnCompletion = true
    basicAnimation.delegate = self

    shape.add(basicAnimation, forKey: "basic")
}

func animationDidStop(_ anim: CAAnimation, finished flag: Bool) {

    if let tmpButton = self.view.viewWithTag(currentSelectedMarker) as? UIButton {
        tmpButton.isSelected = false
    }
}
```

The "currentSelectedMarker" is where the issue is to my knowledge but I am not even sure if that's the best way to go about the problem. Any helps is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add your `Button` `tag` to `CABasicAnimation` using `setValue:forKey:` method like below and get it from the delegate.

```
@objc private func autoUpFillRadial(value: Int, tmpBtn: UIButton, shape: CAShapeLayer){

            let basicAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")
            basicAnimation.toValue = 1
            basicAnimation.duration = CFTimeInterval(value)
            basicAnimation.fillMode = .forwards
            basicAnimation.isRemovedOnCompletion = true
            basicAnimation.setValue(tmpBtn.tag, forKey: "animationID")
            basicAnimation.delegate = self

            shape.add(basicAnimation, forKey: "basic")
        }

        func animationDidStop(_ anim: CAAnimation, finished flag: Bool) {
            if let tag = anim.value(forKey: "animationID") as? Int {
                if let tmpButton = self.view.viewWithTag(tag) as? UIButton {
                    tmpButton.isSelected = false
                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: Thanks Torongo, I tried it but it doesn't work. The animation is played like before and animationDidStop gets called but the rest of the code in it doesn't pass.

Comment: @STerrier I have updated my answer. Please check now. And don't forget to add tags to your button.

Comment: Thanks Torongo! great idea on using the forKey: "animationID"